# Use Cypher Bolt Statement Result Directly in py2neo

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

I have been experimenting with the neo4j library in python, but would like to use some of the functionality provided by py2neo. Currently, I open the driver and session directly from GraphDatabase of neo4j.v1 and use session.run() to execute graph queries. These queries return a `neo4j.v1.result.BoltStatementResult` object.

Rather than having to reformulate my queries to be run from py2neo, I want to convert the `BoltStatementResult` I already have to a form py2neo can process. How do I perform this conversion?